# Media recorder capture video for only 1 seconds

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to capture video using android media recorder but records video for only one second. I have spent one day but can't solved it, what's wrong with my code, Any help will appreciate. Here is code of media capture.

```
    mCamera.unlock();
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(16);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(2000000);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(maxDurationInMs);

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Ethos"
            + File.separator + "Video");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d("Camera Guide", "Required media storage does not exist");
    }

    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "video" + timeStamp + ".mp4");

    SharedPreferenceUtil.putValue("path_video", mediaFile.toString());
    SharedPreferenceUtil.save();

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mediaFile.getPath());



    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(maxFileSizeInBytes);
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);


    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaRecorder.start()
```

I have set maxDurationInMs = 300000

Comment: What is the value of `maxFileSizeInBytes`?

Comment: it is maxFileSizeInBytes = 500000

Comment: This file size resolves to `488 KB`. and you are using high quality encoder which is H.264 and resolution. With all these parameters, your fileSize limit reaches first before your duration limit. Try to comment `fileSize` limit and then check it.

Comment: Thank you now its working but when i run it on nexus its not capturing and gives me error. E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -19 why?

Comment: There can be many reasons for this exception, wrong order of initialization  of MediaRecorder. SO also provides the solutions of this error. I am writing my above comment as Answer, please accept and upvote. Thanks :)

Comment: If you still face issue regarding media recorder preparation, then tell that no solution of SO works.

Answer (score 0):

This file size resolves to `488 KB`. and you are using high quality encoder which is `H.264` and resolution. With all these parameters, your `fileSize` limit reaches first before your duration limit. Try to `comment fileSize limit` and then check it.

hope this helps.